# Silent exception shown in SQL Server Profiler

Tags: sql-server

The following SQL script produces an `Invalid object name '#temp'` exception on SQL Server Profile, but neither **SQL Server Management Studio** nor **sqlcmd** raise the exception:

```
create table #temp (id int)
insert into #temp (id) values (1)
```

I only caught it by running SQL Server Profiler with the event "Exception" turned on, which can be set on the "Events Selection" tab when configuring the trace properties.

Since exceptions tend to slow down the server, I tried a similar code using a table variable:

```
declare @temp table (id int)
insert into @temp (id) values (1)
```

The code above not only avoid the exception, but is also faster when calling it repeatedly, which comproves the performance penalty by using a temporary table:

```
if (db_id('performance_test') is null)
  create database performance_test

go

use performance_test

go

/* --------------------------- */
/* stress test with temp table */
/* --------------------------- */

declare 
  @i int,
  @sql varchar(max),
  @start_time datetime,
  @end_time datetime

set @i = 0

set @sql = 'create table #temp (id int)' + Char(13) + Char(10) + 'insert into #temp (id) values (1)'

set @start_time = getdate()

while (@i < 10000)
begin
  exec (@sql)
  set @i = @i + 1
end

set @end_time = getdate()

select [Elapsed milliseconds] = datediff(millisecond, @start_time, @end_time) -- outputs 17090 milliseconds

go

/* ------------------------------- */
/* stress test with table variable */
/* ------------------------------- */

declare 
  @i int,
  @sql varchar(max),
  @start_time datetime,
  @end_time datetime

set @i = 0

set @sql = 'declare @temp table (id int)' + char(13) + char(10) + 'insert into @temp (id) values (1)'

set @start_time = getdate()

while (@i < 10000)
begin
  exec (@sql)
  set @i = @i + 1
end

set @end_time = getdate()

select [Elapsed milliseconds] = datediff(millisecond, @start_time, @end_time) -- outputs 10010 milliseconds
```

I often read that a **local temporary table** and a **table variable** can be used interchangeably (if using a single batch, of course), however I think the demonstrated behavior above can prove otherwise.

Although it's kinda obvious, it's worth noting that the exception is not raised if we separate the `create table` from `insert into` in different batches:

```
create table #temp (id int)
go
insert into #temp (id) values (1)
```

Is this *silent exception* a SQL Server's bug or is it something that could be called "a feature by design"? Maybe it's simply better to always use table variables instead of temporary tables, given the silent exception above.

P.S.: I've tested on both SQL Server 2014 and SQL Server 2016 Developer editions, getting the same results.

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Comment: Pretty sure the answer to the (non) question can be found here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/turgays/2013/09/17/exec-vs-sp_executesql/

Comment: I'm referring to the exception caused by a `create table` followed by an `insert into`, which was caught using SQL Server Profiler. I'm questioning if the "exception" is a bug or if it was designed to be like that. Maybe creating a table and inserting values in it right away is a bad coding habit, which raises a (silent) exception in SQL Server.

Comment: Creating the temp table will trigger batch recompilation. The initial exception is likely from the `INSERT` being compiled in the batch, and failing (since `#temp` does not yet exist at that point). The batch as a whole does not fail because the second compilation succeeds. No, it is decidedly *not* better to always use table variables, because they have their own issues compared to temp tables (mostly to do with statistics). However, it is true that, despite what you may have heard, temp tables and table variables are not blindly interchangeable, for this and other reasons.

Comment: @JeroenMostert +1 for batch recompilation. I didn't know about it. If it's true, then SQL Server **did** raise an exception. I was starting to think that this behavior was a problem in SQL Server Profiler, not something to expect from the database's engine itself.

Comment: Do note that the load you're stress-testing (create temp table, insert one single row) is not representative of most loads. Recompilation *is* a thing (and it can occasionally seriously impact performance) but usually, whatever's done with the temp table will contribute much more significantly than a few recompilations. Usually. The fact that table variables don't cause recompilation is often a curse in disguise: they won't get up to date statistics either, potentially causing bad query plans, unless (you've guessed it) `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @JeroenMostert, the exception `"Invalid object name"` is probably resolved in the batch recompilation (which I didn't know about). It makes perfect sense considering the "Deferred name Resolution" process, which is a known subject in the SQL Server community.

The first link below is a question I've posted on MSDN and was answered by Mohsin_A_Khan, talking about "Deferred name Resolution" process in SQL Server. The other two links contributes to understand how it actually works:

[Getting "Invalid object name" by creating a temp table and inserting rows right away](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/773b0265-1547-4d8a-9e43-b6a5ab8f33bd/getting-invalid-object-name-by-creating-a-temp-table-and-inserting-rows-right-away?forum=transactsql)

[How to find what caused errors reported in a SQL Server profiler trace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812522/how-to-find-what-caused-errors-reported-in-a-sql-server-profiler-trace)

[Deferred Name Resolution and Compilation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190686%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Since the "Invalid object name" is expected due to the recompilation process and shouldn't be avoided by simply replacing the temporary table with a table variable (again, as pointed out by @JeroenMostert), I consider this question answered.